# Pandas One hot encoding: Bundling together less frequent categories

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I'm doing one hot encoding over a categorical column which has some 18 different kind of values. I want to create new columns for only those values, which appear more than some threshold (let's say 1%), and create another column named `other values` which has 1 if value is other than those frequent values.

I'm using Pandas with Sci-kit learn. I've explored pandas `get_dummies` and sci-kit learn's `one hot encoder`, but can't figure out how to bundle together less frequent values into one column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***plan***

- `pd.get_dummies` to one hot encode as normal
- `sum() < threshold` to identify columns that get aggregated

  - I use `pd.value_counts` with the parameter `normalize=True` to get percentage of occurance.
- `join`

---

```
def hot_mess2(s, thresh):
    d = pd.get_dummies(s)
    f = pd.value_counts(s, sort=False, normalize=True) < thresh
    if f.sum() == 0:
        return d
    else:
        return d.loc[:, ~f].join(d.loc[:, f].sum(1).rename('other'))
```

---

Consider the `pd.Series` `s`

```
s = pd.Series(np.repeat(list('abcdef'), range(1, 7)))

s

0     a
1     b
2     b
3     c
4     c
5     c
6     d
7     d
8     d
9     d
10    e
11    e
12    e
13    e
14    e
15    f
16    f
17    f
18    f
19    f
20    f
dtype: object
```

***`hot_mess(s, 0)`***

```
    a  b  c  d  e  f
0   1  0  0  0  0  0
1   0  1  0  0  0  0
2   0  1  0  0  0  0
3   0  0  1  0  0  0
4   0  0  1  0  0  0
5   0  0  1  0  0  0
6   0  0  0  1  0  0
7   0  0  0  1  0  0
8   0  0  0  1  0  0
9   0  0  0  1  0  0
10  0  0  0  0  1  0
11  0  0  0  0  1  0
12  0  0  0  0  1  0
13  0  0  0  0  1  0
14  0  0  0  0  1  0
15  0  0  0  0  0  1
16  0  0  0  0  0  1
17  0  0  0  0  0  1
18  0  0  0  0  0  1
19  0  0  0  0  0  1
20  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

***`hot_mess(s, .1)`***

```
    c  d  e  f  other
0   0  0  0  0      1
1   0  0  0  0      1
2   0  0  0  0      1
3   1  0  0  0      0
4   1  0  0  0      0
5   1  0  0  0      0
6   0  1  0  0      0
7   0  1  0  0      0
8   0  1  0  0      0
9   0  1  0  0      0
10  0  0  1  0      0
11  0  0  1  0      0
12  0  0  1  0      0
13  0  0  1  0      0
14  0  0  1  0      0
15  0  0  0  1      0
16  0  0  0  1      0
17  0  0  0  1      0
18  0  0  0  1      0
19  0  0  0  1      0
20  0  0  0  1      0
```

Answer (score 4):

How about something like the following:

create a data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=list('abbgcca'), columns=['x'])
df

    x
0   a
1   b
2   b
3   g
4   c 
5   c
6   a
```

Replace values that are present less frequently than a given threshold. I'll create a copy of the column so that I'm not modifying the original dataframe. First step is to create a dictionary of the `value_counts` and then replace the actual values with those counts so that they can be compared to the threshold. Set values below that threshold to 'other values' then use `pd.get_dummies` to get the dummy variables

```
#set the threshold for example 20%
thresh = 0.2
x = df.x.copy()
#replace any values present less than the threshold with 'other values'
x[x.replace(x.value_counts().to_dict()) < len(x)*thresh] = 'other values'
#get dummies
pd.get_dummies(x)

        a       b       c       other values
    0   1.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
    1   0.0     1.0     0.0     0.0
    2   0.0     1.0     0.0     0.0
    3   0.0     0.0     0.0     1.0
    4   0.0     0.0     1.0     0.0
    5   0.0     0.0     1.0     0.0
    6   1.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
```

Alternatively you could use `Counter` it may be a bit cleaner

```
from collections import Counter
x[x.replace(Counter(x)) < len(x)*thresh] = 'other values'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install siuba 
#( in python or anaconda prompth shell)

#use library as:
from siuba.dply.forcats import fct_lump, fct_reorder 

#just like fct_lump of R :

df['Your_column'] = fct_lump(df['Your_column'], n= 10)

df['Your_column'].value_counts() # check your levels

#it reduces the level to 10, lumps all the others as 'Other'
```

R has a good function fct_lump for this purpose, now it is copied to python, simply you select the number of levels to keep and all the other levels will be bundled as 'others' .

Answer (score 0):

#### An improved version:

- The previous solutions do not scale quite well when the dataframe
  is large.
- The situation also becomes complicated when you want to perform one-hot encoding for one column only and your original dataframe has more than one columns.

Here is a more general and scalable (faster) solution.

It is illustrated with an example `df` with two columns and 1 million rows:

```
import pandas as pd
import string
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'1st': [random.sample(["orange", "apple", "banana"], k=1)[0] for i in range(1000000)],\
     '2nd': [random.sample(list(string.ascii_lowercase), k=1)[0] for i in range(1000000)]}
    )
```

The first 10 rows `df.head(10)` is:

```
    1st     2nd
0   banana  t
1   orange  t
2   banana  m
3   banana  g
4   banana  g
5   orange  a
6   apple   x
7   orange  s
8   orange  d
9   apple   u
```

The statistics `df['2nd'].value_counts()` is :

```
s    39004
k    38726
n    38720
b    38699
t    38688
p    38646
u    38638
w    38611
y    38587
o    38576
q    38559
x    38558
r    38545
i    38497
h    38429
v    38385
m    38369
j    38278
f    38262
e    38241
a    38241
l    38236
g    38210
z    38202
c    38058
d    38035
```

###### Step 1: Define threshold

```
threshold = 38500
```

###### Step 2: Focus on the column(s) you want to do one-hot encoding on, and change the entries with frequency lower than the threshold to `others`

```
%timeit df.loc[df['2nd'].value_counts()[df['2nd']].values < threshold, '2nd'] = "others"
```

Time taken is `206 ms ± 346 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`.

###### Step 3: Apply one-hot encoding as usual

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns = ['2nd'], prefix='', prefix_sep='')
```

The first 10 rows after one-hot encoding `df.head(10)` becomes

```
    1st     b   k   n   o   others  p   q   r   s   t   u   w   x   y
0   banana  0   0   0   0   0       0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
1   orange  0   0   0   0   0       0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
2   banana  0   0   0   0   1       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   banana  0   0   0   0   1       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   banana  0   0   0   0   1       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   orange  0   0   0   0   1       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6   apple   0   0   0   0   0       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
7   orange  0   0   0   0   0       0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
8   orange  0   0   0   0   1       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9   apple   0   0   0   0   0       0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
```

###### Step 4 (optional): If you want `others` to be the last column of the `df`, you can try:

```
df = df[[col for col in df.columns if col != 'others'] + ['others']]
```

This shifts `others` to the last column.

```
    1st     b   k   n   o   p   q   r   s   t   u   w   x   y   others
0   banana  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
1   orange  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2   banana  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
3   banana  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
4   banana  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
5   orange  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
6   apple   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
7   orange  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
8   orange  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
9   apple   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
```