# How do I split, categorize, encode and merge this specific column from my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

So the above image shows my X_train after implementing train-test-split on my df. As the value counts suggest that I have many c_names with one count. I thought of implementing one-hot encoding on c_name column but that would create a lot of columns [(n-1) columns]. I have approx 4500 c_names with count 1.

Is there an efficient way I could merge all c_names with count in the range 1-35 in a new column 'Others' and encode the c_name column efficiently and merge with my df.

[image]

I tried defining threshold and then splitting them into 'Others' column. I dont know how to proceed further ahead. I want the encoded c_name column merged with other columns of the df.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [one hot encoding for frequent values only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44527731/one-hot-encoding-for-frequent-values-only)

Comment: [Please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), provide a MRE instead (see: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Comment: @Priyank I have produced the 'Others' column and bifurcated the data exactly in a similar way as your linked post. I just wanted to know how to merge it and whether there is any better approach than mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
# Same as value_counts but broadcast values on each row
m = df.groupby('c_name').transform('size') < threshold

# one-hot encoding
c_names = pd.get_dummies(df['c_name'].mask(m, other='Others'), 
                         prefix='name', dtype=int)

# merge to original dataframe
df = pd.concat([df, c_names], axis=1)
```

Comment: Glad to help you. If you use ML, it could be interesting to use `OneHotEncoder`, `ColumnTransformer` and `Pipeline` objects from `sklearn`. You can use read [6.1. Pipelines and composite estimators](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html)

Comment: Thanks, I am using ColumnTransformer for implementing different encoding techniques on different columns. I'll learn more about pipelines though, thanks for the resource!